# Next.js page is blank in production

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, google-tag-manager

I have a website using NextJS(11.0.0) and hosted at AWS, I've been having this problem where a few pages didn't load, they just stay blank, on the site in production, this problem doesn't occur when running locally or hosting this same project at Vercel, the only messages that appear in the browser console are these:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

Uncaught ReferenceError: webVitals is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:188
    at gtm.js?id=GTM-MBGSVH:456:414
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (gtm.js?id=GTM-MBGSVH:457:118)
```

if I type a random route like: "/somethingRandom gives the same error,so it's like this page doesn't exist, the problem doesn't seem to be in the code as everything works running locally or on Vercel.
I believe it is nothing related to web-vitals or AdBlock as some people thought, for me feels like Next.js or my Server is not rendering this page.

Does anyone have any idea what this error could be related to?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `gtm.js` which is Google Tag Manager, disable/remove GTM and check the page.

Once verified this is the cause:

Within GTM there is a template for core web vitals, you can disable it from the workspace to get GTM to work but skip webvitals

You can see this article that describes how to add but you can CWW into GA4

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-core-web-vitals-in-ga4-with-google-tag-manager/